# Does VS 2017 allow two datasets for an rdlc report?

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2017, rdlc

I have a framework for my applications that hold reports that are printed from the application. I have one report that I'm trying to add a second dataset to but I keep getting the error "A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'DataSetTwo'". Is it impossible to add a second dataset to a report?

The reason I'm adding a second data source is I have one that will populate nearly all information on the report and then the second is going to be used for a tablix in the report. I can't use the first dataset because for some reason the group by is not working on the SQL statement so I'm going to add a new dataset with less fields so the group by isn't a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error

> A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'DataSetTwo'

indicate you had not supply the data source.

When you generate the report, did you supply the second dataset?

It should look something like this:

```
ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
ReportDataSource rd1 = new ReportDataSource("DataSetOne", dataset1);
ReportDataSource rd2 = new ReportDataSource("DataSetTwo", dataset2);
ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rd1);
ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rd2);
ReportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
```