# RDLC report throws an error with input parameter?

Tags: c#, xsd, parameter-passing, visual-studio-2019, rdlc

I'm use “Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Versione 16.9.3”
with c# language.To use RDLC reports I have installed the following packages:

- Report viewer 15.0.0.0
- Microsoft Report Viewer Control for ASP.Net Web Forms applications. 150.1449.0
- Microsoft Report Viewer Control for .Net Windows Forms applications. 150.1449.0

1. I create a Dataset connected to my DB and a table inside it.
2. I create a rdlc report by connecting to created Dataset.
3. I create a form and inside it I insert the ReportViewer connected to the report rdlc.
   ***So everything works perfectly***.
   If I insert a parameter in the report, the print preview no longer works with the error "A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'DataSet'".

I realized that the header in the rdcl has been changed, before entering the parameter is:

> xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/**2008**/01/reportdefinition"
> xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">

**after entering the input parameter:**

> xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/**2016**/01/reportdefinition"
> xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">

Does anyone have a solution?
Now I have entered the static parameters into the table but it is not an "elegant" solution.

Comment: Did you add the RDLC report file to the SQL Server report manager?

Comment: Better show your code, I can only guess this is related to coding issue. Do you call LocalReport.SetParameters() before you render?

Comment: @jdweng
I'm using mysql, I don't think it has a Server Report

Comment: Your schema is using a SQL Server which may be the reason for the exception.  Looks like reports are rpt in mysql.  See : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-crystal-displaying.html?force_isolation=true

Comment: @5DN1L:
I copy part of  code which is very simple,  I have to pass only 2 strings, in practice add 2 variables to the call and into the report add 2 input var (with report editor):

string dsForn = cmbFornitore.SelectedItem.ToString();
string data = String.Format("{0:yyyy}", dtFine.Value);
rptSemeFornitoriPreview rpt = new rptSemeFornitoriPreview(dsForn,data);
rpt.Show();

Comment: Can you check does the constructor method rptSemeFornitoriPreview(string, string) include the data source in the report? It should be something like LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);

Comment: @ZakRoma Check my answer on by other thread, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60289773/does-vs-2017-allow-two-datasets-for-an-rdlc-report/60292069#60292069

Comment: Hi @ZakRoma have you made any progress on this? I have experienced this and, for now, have taken to leaving the parameter out of the report, and post-processing the RDLC file in Notepad++ by manually adding in the ReportParameters XML fragment. I believe it happens because VS2019/SSDT is doing this, but I have no solution as yet.

Comment: Hi @sasfrog, no I have not done any more tests to continue the development by the deadline. When I needed parameter filtered data I created a specific report table by passing parameters to the query.

Comment: i had same issue, turns out the parameter I was passing had an equal sign at the beginning of it.  it interpreted it as an expression.  had to remove the leading equal sign